# Menu of canvas Ajuda

Tags: php, javascript

Eai galera , tenho um menu aqui que ao clicar ne um ícone ele aparece.
como faço p/ quando o usuário entrar na página ele ja exibir o menu ?

Grato :D

```
Index -> 
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Off-Canvas Menu Effects - Side Slide</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Modern effects and styles for off-canvas navigation with CSS transitions and SVG animations using Snap.svg" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="sidebar, off-canvas, menu, navigation, effect, inspiration, css transition, SVG, morphing, animation" />
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu_sideslide.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-wrap">
            <nav class="menu">
             <a href="#"><span><?php echo $nome; ?></span></a>
                <div class="icon-list">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i><span> <?php echo $saldo; ?></span></a>
                    <hr size='2'>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>Extratos</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><span>Rede Credenciada</span></a>
                    <a href="sair.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><span>Sair</span></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Menu</button>
        </div>
        <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="content">
                <iframe id="klaus" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://cartao3.algorix.com/Ciclum/Atend/LoginCliente.aspx" scrolling="yes"  /></iframe>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content-wrap -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS's

```
(function() {
    var bodyEl = document.body,
        content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
        openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
        closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),
        isOpen = false;
    function init() {
        initEvents();
    }
    function initEvents() {
        openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        if( closebtn ) {
            closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        }

        // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
        content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( isOpen && target !== openbtn ) {
                toggleMenu();
        }
    } );
}

function toggleMenu() {
    if( isOpen ) {
        classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    }
    else {
        classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
}

init();

})();
```

Comment: window.onload("#classname"); Adiciona isso no javascript

Answer (score 0):

Basta chamar `toggleMenu` quando a página for carregada.

Observação: a função `init` deveria ser executada quando a página fosse carregada também, pois dependendo da posição do seu elemento `script`, os eventos podem não ser adicionadas aos elementos na sua página. Se o `script` é declarado no fim da tag `body` na página, então está tudo bem.

```
(function() {

    var r = (window["requestAnimationFrame"] ||
             window["webkitRequestAnimationFrame"] ||
             window["mozRequestAnimationFrame"] ||
             window["msRequestAnimationFrame"] ||
             function(b) { setTimeout(b, 16) });

    (function c() {
        // Checa se a página foi carregada
        if(document["readyState"] === "complete")
            // Faz qualquer coisa...
            init(), toggleMenu();
        // Se não, então checa novamente
        else r(c);
    })();

})();
```